# Asp.net process.start own issues

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a asp.net application where I am using running process.start. it runs on my pc but not the server.

I have read that I needed to give my iis worker permission to run interactivity with the desktop however this still is not working.on my server the asp.net app is under its own application pool. How do I give my application pool access to run the process.start?

Comment: I'm not sure but it might require `Network Service` identity for your `App Pool`.

Comment: How do you set that?

Comment: Please refer [this](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) article

Comment: What are you running with `Process.Start`? There may be some other way of doing it that does not require compromising the security of the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Give permission for ASP.NET worker process account (\ASPNET) to interact with desktop or allow ASP.NET worker process to run in SYSTEM account.

To know how to allow worker process to run in SYSTEM account and to know the default permissions of ASPNET account, check this article
               INFO: Process and Request Identity in ASP.NET (http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;317012)
  2. Enable IIS Admin Service to interact with desktop

To configure this, follow this steps.

a. Open Control Panel and follow these steps: 
                            For Windows NT: click Services. 
                            For Windows 2000, Windows XP, and .NET Server: click Administrative Tools, and then click Services.

b. Double-click IIS Admin Service.

c. On the Log On tab, select the Allow Service to Interact with Desktop check box.
                  Note: This article assumes that the IIS Admin Service runs as a local system.

d. Stop and restart the IIS Admin Service.

Then you need to change you Application Pool Identity to Local Service. Start and Stop Application Pool and Website.

Then this will work

Comment: Is there a way to do it without compromising the security of the server so much?

Comment: @Krev32 It is probably best not to connect the server to the Internet in that configuration as there could be an unknown vulnerability in IIS which, as you have now given it full access to the entire system, could result in it and any other other computers on its local network being taken over.